# strange error with siunitx and sans serif font

Tags: siunitx

After reinstalling my system, I'm getting a weird `"Parameters must be numbered consecutively."` error message when trying to use siunitx with a sans serif font.

Here is a minimal example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

I'm using Fedora 16 with a (non-full) Texlive 2011 installation, on my old system with Fedora 15 and a complete Texlive 2011 everything compiled fine. Also, the error doesn't occur when I remove the line with the font command.

Complete pdflatex output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./PRGLBE_01.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, po
lish, german, ngerman, swissgerman, italian, ukenglish, usenglishmax, czech, du
tch, basque, slovak, catalan, portuguese, french, spanish, german-x-2011-07-01,
ngerman-x-2011-07-01, galician, loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3names.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3bootstrap.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3basics.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3expan.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3tl.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3seq.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3int.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3quark.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3prg.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3clist.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3token.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3prop.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3msg.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3io.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3file.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3skip.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3keys.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3fp.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3box.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3coffins.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3color.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3luatex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/translator.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/translator-language-
mappings.tex))) (./PRGLBE_01.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
! Parameters must be numbered consecutively.
<to be read again> 
              ##
l.4 \begin{document}
```

Comment: Transient bug in v2.4a of `siunitx`. This should already be fixed on CTAN: can you use `\listfiles` to check which version you have?

Comment: Yes, I'm using 2011/12/04 v2.4a. :) Thanks for the quick reply and all the work you're doing on siunitx!